# input_size for non-lazy modules in PyTorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, lstm

Some modules in `PyTorch`, such as [`LSTM`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html), don't yet have a "[lazy](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.modules.lazy.LazyModuleMixin.html#torch.nn.modules.lazy.LazyModuleMixin)" implementation (like [`LazyLinear`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LazyLinear.html#torch.nn.LazyLinear)). Is there a hack around this issue to make these modules behave just like the lazy modules (instantiated when given the first input based on its shape)?